# React hook is not reflected in function

Tags: reactjs

my friends!
I'm struggling with React and hooks.
I do a UseEffect where I store info into `sites` dict, but this is not reflected inside a function called by a Component.

```
 const [sites, setSites] = useState([])

  useEffect(()=>{
    const bearer = "Bearer asdf12345"
      console.log(bearer)
      const res = axios.get("https://the_api.com/v1/klasses/sites?pageSize=1000", {
          headers: {
            "Authorization": bearer}
        }).then(function (response) {
          const data = response.data.data;
          if (data.length > 0){
              let sd = {}
              data.forEach(function(site){
                site.attributes.data.forEach(function(subsite){
                  let label = site.attributes.custom.nameStr+"-"+Object.keys(subsite)
                  sd[label] = subsite[Object.keys(subsite)]
                })
              })
              setSites(sd)
          }
          console.log(sites)
        })
        console.log(sites)
  }, [])

  function dataChange(prev, next, coord){
    console.log(next.value)
    if (coord.column == 2) {
      console.log(sites) // here the object is empty
      console.log(next["value"])
      console.log(sites.hasOwnProperty(next["value"]))
      console.log(next["value"] in sites)
      console.log(sites[next["value"]])
      if (!(sites.hasOwnProperty(next["value"]))) alert( next["value"] + "is not in sites")
    }
  }

return (
      <CRow>
        <CCol xl={12}>
          <CCard>
            <CCardHeader>
              Create users in bulk
            </CCardHeader>
            <CCardBody>
              <Spreadsheet     
                data={spreadsheetData}
                columnLabels={columns}
                onCellCommit={dataChange}
              />   
            </CCardBody>
            <CCardFooter>
              <CButton color="success" >Save</CButton>
            </CCardFooter>
          </CCard>
          </CCol>
        <CCol xl={12}>
        </CCol>
      </CRow>
    )
```

Any idea? I am super lost.

Comment: `sites` is `const`. Your component is called a second time, creating a new closure that your `console.log()` statements don't have access to. They're referencing `sites` from the closure of the initial render.

Comment: I don't think I get what you are meaning, I'm pretty new to React

Comment: Put your `console.log(sites)` outside of the `useEffect()`. The first time it will be empty for the initial state, second time it will have the populated values from your axios call.

Comment: but why the data is not populated in the `dataChange` function, for the `Spreadsheet` component?